# Is there a way to change the column widths of a table inside Word through PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ms-word, properties

I have been trying to create a PowerShell script that edits columns of a table inside of a document.

This is what I am trying to run:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

# Initialize Word application
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $True

# Open the document
$doc = $word.Documents.Open("C:\temp.docx")

# Get the table
$table = $doc.Tables.Item(1)

# change orientation of doc
$doc.PageSetup.Orientation = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOrientation]::wdOrientLandscape

# Set behavior of table to autofitcontent 
$table.AutoFitBehavior = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAutoFitBehavior]::wdAutoFitContent

# Set overall width of table
$table.PreferredWidth = InchesToPoints(10.3)

#set column width
$table.Columns[1].Width = InchesToPoints(0.19)
$table.Columns[2].Width = InchesToPoints(2.92)
$table.Columns[3].Width = InchesToPoints(0.81)
$table.Columns[4].Width = InchesToPoints(1.71)
$table.Columns[5].Width = InchesToPoints(3.1)
$table.Columns[6].Width = InchesToPoints(1.55)



# Save and close the document
$doc.Save()
$doc.Close()

# Quit the Word application
$word.Quit()
```

And I am getting the following errors:

```
AutoFitBehavior' is not a property.
At C:\temp.ps1:14 char:1
+ $table.AutoFitBehavior = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAutoFitBeha ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

InchesToPoints : The term 'InchesToPoints' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\temp.ps1:16 char:25
+ $table.PreferredWidth = InchesToPoints(10.3)
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (InchesToPoints:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Cannot access individual columns in this collection because the table has mixed cell widths.
At C:\temp.ps1:20 char:1
+ $table.Columns[1].Width = InchesToPoints(0.19)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Cannot access individual columns in this collection because the table has mixed cell widths.
At C:\temp.ps1:21 char:1
+ $table.Columns[2].Width = InchesToPoints(2.92)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Cannot access individual columns in this collection because the table has mixed cell widths.
At C:\temp.ps1:22 char:1
+ $table.Columns[3].Width = InchesToPoints(0.81)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Cannot access individual columns in this collection because the table has mixed cell widths.
At C:\temp.ps1:23 char:1
+ $table.Columns[4].Width = InchesToPoints(1.71)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Cannot access individual columns in this collection because the table has mixed cell widths.
At C:\temp.ps1:24 char:1
+ $table.Columns[5].Width = InchesToPoints(3.1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Cannot access individual columns in this collection because the table has mixed cell widths.
At C:\temp.ps1:25 char:1
+ $table.Columns[6].Width= InchesToPoints(1.55)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

I also tried the following:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
$wordAssembly = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application].Assembly
# Initialize Word application
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $True

# Open the document
$doc = $word.Documents.Open("C:\temp.docx")

# Get the table
$table = $doc.Tables(1)

$table.AutoFitBehavior = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAutoFitBehavior]::wdAutoFitContent


$doc.PageSetup.Orientation = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOrientation]::wdOrientLandscape

$table.Columns(1).Width = 72*0.19
$table.Columns(2).Width = 72*2.92
$table.Columns(3).Width = 72*0.81
$table.Columns(4).Width = 72*1.71
$table.Columns(5).Width = 72*3.1
$table.Columns(6).Width= 72*1.55



# Save and close the document
$doc.Save()
$doc.Close()

# Quit the Word application
$word.Quit()
$version = $wordAssembly.FullName
$version


[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word)
```

I tried using a couple of different approaches, I tried $word.InchesToPoints, CentimetersToPoints, $word.CentimetersToPoints, converting the inches to points, nothing seemed to work. I looked up some of the documentation, and InchesToPoints should work.

I messed around with the autofitbehavior, but nothing that I changed worked.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: `AutoFitBehavior` is indeed not a property, but a Method. Try with `$table.AutoFitBehavior([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAutoFitBehavior]::wdAutoFitContent)` although if you want to set the column widths yourself, I think you want `wdAutoFitFixed` instead. Also `InchesToPoints` is a method of the Application, ergo `$table.Columns[1].Width = $word.InchesToPoints(0.19)` instead of `$table.Columns[1].Width = InchesToPoints(0.19)`

Comment: That worked, thank you so much. Doesn't wdAutoFitFixed make all of the columns the same width?

Comment: The whole idea here is for you to set the columns widths manually and with wdAutoFitFixed **you** decide how wide the entire table and its columns should be. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdautofitbehavior): _wdAutoFitFixed: The table is set to a fixed size, regardless of the content, and is not automatically sized._